# xCode XIB Storyboard loosing elements when adding or editing others

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I am using the XIB for a UITableViewCell, I had many elements, but when adding a new view, or editing a view, button, etc it would just lose other elements. ie:

I have an imageview and add a normal view:

[image: imageview and normalview]

then I try to make the normal view smaller and I lose the imageView, it says it is out of the content view block:

[image: editing normal view loses imageview]

WTF xCode?

Can anybody help? I have tried restarting and creating a new file.

Comment: which version of xcode you are using ?

Comment: @sheshnath I am using 6.1

Comment: actually, it's happens with me too. and i think it's issue with xcode 6.1, when you got the solution please share with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to me. From the list of objects, click on the missing one and redo the xyhw properties. I think it's a bug but can be easily worked around.